# Why can't I get a List<long> from a database with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I've got a weird problem. I can use LINQ to get all of the rows in my database, but I can't get a List of the contents of one of the columns.

In the code below, "Derfus" is ends up being a List object and I can use the debugger to look at the list contents. "NewsItem" is the class name for the elements of the database. In each element of the Derfus list, the m_ItemId member variable is set to a non-zero value that I can see with the debugger. This is what I want, and I could use a loop to get these values. But I seem to have something wrong with my LINQ syntax on the second line because IdList, which is a List as expected, contains all zeros. IdList contains the right number of elements, the same as Derfus contains, but not the values that I expect.

```
var Derfus = ( from e in Context.Table select e ).ToList();
var IdList = ( from e in Context.Table select e.m_ItemId ).ToList();
```

These lines are one after another in the code. The table does contain m_ItemId as a column and it is a "long".

I am not sure what other code to show. Since the lines both compile, and lots of other functions work properly with this database, I don't know what else could be relevant. Here's the NewsItem definition:

```
public class NewsItem 
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.Indexed]
    public int m_Id { get; set; }
    public long m_ItemId { get; set; }
    public String m_Title { get; set; }
    public String m_Subtitle { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Note that I am using SQLite but it should not cause me problems like this, should it?

Comment: That seems like a strange bug. Worse comes to worse though, you could use linq to actually select the idlist out of Derfus if needed though...

Comment: I wrote a loop to extract he ID values from the list of database items. At least writing c# code lets me use a debugger on it if it doesn't work right. I'm having a love-hate relationship with LINQ, XAML, Binding, and other technologies that stop me from debugging broken code.